# Clang C++20 Module in shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, clang++, c++20, c++-modules

### Is it possible to expose C++ module through shared library?

I realize this is the bleeding edge (Jan 2021), but I still dare to ask if anyone would know how to accomplish exposing a module through a shared library.

This is the Makefile:

```
CPP=clang++-11 -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fms-extensions
MOD_EXP=-fmodules-ts --precompile -x c++-module
MOD_IMP=-fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=.
USE_STD_MOD=-fimplicit-modules -fimplicit-module-maps
DLL_EXP=-fvisibility=default

main: main.cpp mathlib
    $(CPP) $(DLL_EXP) $(USE_STD_MOD)  $< -o $@ libmathlib.so -Wl,-rpath,./

mathlib: addlib.cpp sublib.cpp
    $(CPP) $(MOD_EXP) $^
    $(CPP) $(DLL_EXP) -shared *.pcm -o libmathlib.so

clean:
    rm -f *.pcm *.so main
```

The code is as simple as I could imagine:

```cpp
// addlib.cpp
export module addlib;

export __attribute__((visibility("default"))) int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

The codefile 'sublib.cpp' has a corresponding function which subtracts b from a.

And the main file:

```cpp
import addlib;
import sublib;
import <iostream>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "3 + 5 = "
              << add(3, 5) << "\n";
    std::cout << "8 - 2 = "
              << sub(8, 2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I purposefully removed `$(MOD_IMP)` from the compilation command to build main, since I wanted to be dependent upon the shared library only. However, I get this compiler error

```
main.cpp:1:8: fatal error: module 'addlib' not found
```

Comment: Well, module is not a namespace. What you link is what you link. You may just do `int add(int,int); int sub(int,int); int main() { ... }`

Comment: @KamilCuk So I need to link to the module? Do you know how to do that? And no, I cannot use what you suggest. I realize my example program is very simple, but that is because it is an example. I have a major project that I'm right now thinking about how to port to C++20. And it compiles to a shared library.

Comment: Also, submodules are currently not supported by clang11. But I'm hoping for clang12 support for that.